# Auto-resize image view to fit small screen sizes

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, imageview, drawable

I have an image in my **ConstraintLayout** that I want to resize according to different screen sizes.
It is fine with large screens, but not with **small** ones.

Here is my image view

```
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_app_image_start_screen_fragment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:src="@drawable/my_image"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following property of Imageview

android:scaleType="fitXY"

Answer (score 0):

They key to do that is to use percentages instead of defined widths or height. So that as per different screen sizes, it can adjust.

The property for that is `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio`, so you will have to modify your current layout as follows

```xml
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_app_image_start_screen_fragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1"
        android:src="@drawable/my_image"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />
```

Note we have made both `width` and `height` as `0dp` and as you can see the dimension ratio is `1` which mean for now width is equal to height.

You can adjust the dimension ratio as per your need and can read more about it [here](https://medium.com/@sasanksunkavalli/android-constraintlayout-layout-constraintdimensionratio-33bd2293f34c).